# Update package.json file with grunt dependencies

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs, gulp

After initializing my project with grunt dependencies I noticed that package.json file was not updated. It was partially my fault because I am switching from gulp to grunt so all I did was delete the content under "devDependencies" and that must have conflicted.

I have all the packages I need, is there an automated way to update the "devDependencies" section without having to run my npm routine again?

I understand I can update the devDependencies section manually but I rather let the system find out what items are already downloaded and update package.json automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see it is to do it manually. One thing that can help you with the names and version numbers in by executing:

`npm list`

Which will show which packages are extraneous (installed but not in your `package.json` file.

You could write a bash script to extract those and install them automatically but I don't see the need for that effort here.